# Disabling SSLv3

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I'm relatively new/nervous around server tweaks. I've been tasked with disabling SSLv3 on a clients site. They use Amazon EC2 for their hosting.

I've managed to locate where I need to make the changes.

in file

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
```

we have the following

```
#   The protocols to enable.
#   Available values: all, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
#   SSL v2  is no longer supported
SSLProtocol all
```

A lot of the guides online say to change it to

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

But in the comments on the server it says SSL v2 is no longer supported.

What are the issues with moving this to one of the TLS versions being so SSLv2 is disabled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Test your server against https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html there may be other tweeks you need to apply.

Answer (score 4):

No issues at all, unless you have some *really* old clients talking to your server. If this is the case it is the clients that need to be updated.

SSLv2 was deprecated a long time ago and it's now several years since SSLv3 was also deprecated.

You can probably afford to use `-TLSv1` as well, leaving just TLSv1.1 and v1.2

You should also restrict the SSL Ciphers your server uses.

EDIT: There is an excellent starting point for a secure SSL server setup here: https://cipherli.st/

Comment: So would I change the  value to 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1

I'm assuming this means all except SSLv2, SSLv3 TLSv1

Comment: That is correct. You *may* need to update the `ssl libraries` if you are using an old version.

Comment: @ShaneJones Yes, exactly. And as suggested, restrict the ciphers, too, since some are vulnerable (RC4). Best idea would be that you check the site for vulnerabilty with a tool like this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest